# Replace `?` key with `h` key in GNU argp

Tags: c, argp

I'm using the `argp.h` library to parse command line arguments for my program.

I setup it a little and works, but there is just a thing I don't like.

When I run my program with `--help` it show this:

```
-?, --help                 Give this help list
    --usage                Give a short usage message
-V, --version              Print program version
```

Which is correct, but why the short for `--help` is `-?`? Is it possible to specify a different key, like `-h` with a macro maybe?

I took a look at the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp.html) but I didn't find any info about this, except maybe define a custom key, but I don't like this approach or better, I don't know if this is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some digging around reveals the [location](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L80) in which `'?'` is defined as the short option for the default help functionality.

Without getting too lost in the source, it appears that when the default help is enabled, the user's *argp* and default *argp* (and if applicable, the version *argp*) are [grouped together as siblings](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L897) (see also: [children](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp-Children.html)), and then the program arguments are parsed. There does not appear to be an interface for changing the default values before this occurs, as the short option is [hard coded](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L94).

Turning off the default help / usage options is possible by passing the `ARGP_NO_HELP` [flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp-Flags.html) to `argp_parse`.

[`argp_state_help`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp-Helper-Functions.html) can be used to [replicate the behaviour](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L90) of the default options, using various [flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp-Help-Flags.html). The flags used by the default options are:

- `--help`: `ARGP_HELP_STD_HELP`
- `--usage`: `ARGP_HELP_USAGE | ARGP_HELP_EXIT_OK`

Where `ARGP_HELP_EXIT_OK` results in `exit(0)`.

If not using [`argp_program_version_hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/2.37/html_node/Argp-Global-Variables.html) the behaviour of [`--version`](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L147) is to simply print `argp_program_version`.

A rough example:

```
#include <argp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USAGE 0x123

const char *argp_program_version = "example 1.0";
const char *argp_program_bug_address = "<so@example.com>";

static struct argp_option options[] = {
    { "help", 'h', 0, 0, "show this message", -1 },
    { "version", 'V', 0, 0, "show version", -1 },
    { "usage", USAGE, 0, 0, "show usage", 0 },
    { 0 }
};

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
    switch (key) {
        case 'h':
            argp_state_help(state, state->out_stream, ARGP_HELP_STD_HELP);
            break;
        case USAGE:
            argp_state_help(state, state->out_stream, ARGP_HELP_USAGE | ARGP_HELP_EXIT_OK);
            break;
        case 'V':
            fprintf(state->out_stream, "%s\n", argp_program_version)
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt };
    argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, ARGP_NO_HELP, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just have a question. Shouldn't `usage` be in the same group as the other ones (`-1`)?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but apparently not, according to the [source](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/argp-parse.c#L81).

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with simply supporting `-h` without it being listed in the help and usage messages you can get away with way a rather simple solution, namely adding `-h` as an extra hidden option:

Add this to your normal `struct argp_option` array:

```
{ NULL, 'h', 0, OPTION_HIDDEN, NULL, -1 },
```

and then call the built-in help if it is detected:

```
case 'h':
    argp_state_help(state, state->out_stream, ARGP_HELP_STD_HELP);
    break;
```